# NSError domain check condition fails in iOS 8

Tags: ios, if-statement, nserror

I am using `WKWebView` for iOS 8 devices and want to check if the error occuring is `NSURLErrorDomain` then I want to make some changes, until now, I have added below code, but somehow the compiler goes into else part, now sure why.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if ( [error domain] == NSURLErrorDomain )
    {
        //code here
    }
    else
    {
        //But compiler always comes here
    }
 }
```

The error I do get is 'NSURLErrorDomain', but compiler is not executing if loop and goes in else part. Can anyone tell me why it is?

Comment: Definately means.? try to print and check the domain type.

Comment: I mean to say, it is 'NSURLErrorDomain'

Comment: `domain` property of error is a NSString. So `isEqualToString:` instead of `==`.

Comment: Try Glorfindel's answer it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`domain` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/domain) is an `NSString`, so you need to compare it like this:

```
if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]) {
```

To give an idea of how the developers at Apple would handle this, check the code below which is copied from the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html), listing 2-3:

```
NSString *errorMsg;
if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]) {
    switch ([error code]) {
        case NSURLErrorCannotFindHost:
            errorMsg = NSLocalizedString(@"Cannot find specified host. Retype URL.", nil);
            break;
        case NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost:
            errorMsg = NSLocalizedString(@"Cannot connect to specified host. Server may be down.", nil);
            break;
        case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
            errorMsg = NSLocalizedString(@"Cannot connect to the internet. Service may not be available.", nil);
            break;
        default:
            errorMsg = [error localizedDescription];
            break;
    }
} else {
    errorMsg = [error localizedDescription];
}
```

Comment: Domain property is NSString. But NSURLErrorDomain's property is int. Then how it works.. Please check your answer..

Comment: No, [`NSURLErrorDomain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSURL_Domain) is an `NSString` as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes) the `domain` value will be `@"NSURLErrorDomain"` with an error code defined by the `enum` starting with `NSURLErrorXxx`.

Therefore you want:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"] &&
        [error code] == NSURLErrorTimedOut )    // for example
    {
        // Handle timeout
    }
    else
    {
        // Some other error
    }
 }
```